# How do I install missing manpages in a chroot running in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, chroot, manpage

I am on the new Ubuntu tablet from bq, in a terminal, running in a chroot jail.

I have installed `man-db`, `manpages`, `manpages-dev`, and even `ubuntu-docs`.

But while `man man` works, or `man gpp` or other things I installed manually, basic manpages are missing and undocumented. `man less` doesn't work, nor `man ls` or `man apt-get`.

How do I get these installed as well?

Answer (score 1):

The man pages and man tool simply need be installed, and you need to be running the command within the chroot after doing `sudo chroot .` inside its root directory.

If man pages aren't working, then likely there is some other underlying issue, such as the files have somehow been removed from disk. I just tested here on my Nexus 4, and `man ls` in the chroot works just fine.